# PowerShell script to copy files ordered by size

Tags: powershell

In a script that runs in the morning, I need to copy files from one server to another, and I plan to copy larger files first, and did so:

```
Get-ChildItem | sort -property Length -Descending | Copy-Item $LOCAL_BKP_TEMP\* -Destination $LOCAL_BKP_FINAL -PassThru
```

Gives the following error:

```
Copy-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem | sort -property Length -Descending  | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Copy-Item -Destination $LOCAL_BKP_FINAL
```

Comment: There is no need to expand the fullname because copy-item should accept it as valuefrompipelinebypropertyname.

Comment: Didn't work. Returned error: "Copy-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties 
do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input."

Comment: Could someone suggest another option?

Comment: and don't add `$LOCAL_BKP_TEMP\*` into your `copy-item` command, that is what cause the error

Comment: It worked! Honestly, I hadn't realized the detail of not adding $LOCAL_ BKP_TEMP\\* into copy-item command. Thank you!